# Option "width" is not allowed in the new version of overpic (Jan 5th, 2024)

Tags: overpic

I was happily using overpic, with the following MWE (replace Annulus-PBma-essai.pdf by any .pdf file)

```
\documentclass [12pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\center\begin{overpic}[width=10cm]{Annulus-PBma-essai.pdf}
 \put (32,65) {$z_{0}$}  
    \put (52,44){$z_1$}   
\end{overpic}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

That is until the new version of overpic, which does not seem to accept "width" as an option. I thus get an error message. Did I miss something, and if not, is there a way to get the same effect as "width" with the new version. [Sorry I can not reproduce the error message ( had to do with setkeyval), since I updated my office computer but not my home computer.]

Here is the full log

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Untitled.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2024-01-04>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsbook.cls
Document Class: amsbook 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/overpic/overpic.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eepic/epic.sty
Enhancements to Picture Environment. Version 1.2 - Released June 1, 1986
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./Untitled.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/grfext/grfext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty))
 (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))

pdfTeX warning: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex (file ./DS4-3-image1b.pdf): PDF in
clusion: found PDF version <1.6>, but at most version <1.5> allowed

./Untitled.tex:8: Package xkeyval Error: `width' undefined in families `OVP'.

See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.8 ...gin{overpic}[width=10cm]{DS4-3-image1b.pdf}
                                                  
? 
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} <./DS4
-3-image1b.pdf, page is rotated 270 degrees>] (./Untitled.aux) )</usr/local/tex
live/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi12.pfb></usr/local/texl
ive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb></usr/local/texlive
/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr9.pfb>
Output written on Untitled.pdf (1 page, 84995 bytes).
SyncTeX written on Untitled.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on Untitled.log.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As of 2024, the package uses a custom name space for the keys. However, I cannot reproduce the problem you are encountering with the current version of the package (2024/01/06 2.1). The most recent version is from yesterday, so maybe try to update again if this is not yet installed on your machine.

Comment: I get no error if I replace your picture with example-image. Show your log-file.

Comment: You should replace `\center` by `\centering`. `\center` would start a `trivlist` environment, which is ended only implicitly by the end of the `figure` environment.

Comment: I get with today's version (I tried both with and without xkeyval package) : pdfTeX warning: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex (file ./DS4-3-image1b.pdf): PDF inclusion: found PDF version <1.6>, but at most version <1.5> allowed
/Sans-titre.tex:12: Package xkeyval Error: `width' undefined in families `OVP'
.See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
l.12 ...gin{overpic}[width=10cm]{Annulus-PBma-essai.pdf}
 ?

Comment: do not show only a snippet. Show the full log. Add it to your question.

Comment: why are you using colordvi (from 1992) instead of color or xcolor?

Comment: Sorry, I just changed (and replaced colordvi by xcolor)

Comment: well this is not the log file but only the terminal output. Why does the example load xkeyval (that is reponsable for the error)? Your code doesn't do that for me.

Comment: I opened an issue https://github.com/rolfn/overpic/issues/7

Comment: This is now fixed in overpic 2.1 which is now available on TeXlive.Thanks Ulrike!